# Returning data to a client through a different port

Tags: java, sockets, wget

Im using `wget` to request for a page through a proxy and using storm to perform some processing(all that is not relevant in this context, hopefully) but, the gist of the problem is this.

1. Client with `ClientInetAddress : ClientPort` sends a request to Server with `ServerInetAddress : ServerPort1`.
2. But the socket created at the Server program had to be closed and could not be opened again.
3. But a response with some data needs to be sent back to the client.
4. This is done through a socket with `ServerInetAddress : ServerPort2` and is sent back to the Client's socket with `ClientInetAddress : ClientPort`.

As seen, a seperate port is used to sent data back to the client. The request was sent using `wget` so, Im guessing there is a listener there waiting for a response.

My question is, does the listener check if the data coming back is from the same Server port(ServerPort1) that it was sent to? Because I've tried a scenario and I'm getting a `Connection Refused` exception, even though I'm sending to the same port(which should have a listener).

The method used to return data was

```
Socket clientSocket=new Socket('<ClientInetAddress>','<ClientPort>');
```

This generates the error I guess. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why (2)? Why was the socket closed? This is a *bug*. Your design is flawed.

The reason for the error is that the client doesn't have a listening socket. Clients don't. Servers do.

So what you're trying to do is impossible.

Fix your design.

Comment: Pardon my lack of experience, but, I'm confused here. When a browser sends a request to a server, the response from the server has to reach the browser, right? So, how does this happen? As in, to which port does the server send data to?

Comment: The response is sent back via the same connection the request was received on. There is no second connection, second port, etc.

Comment: I understand. I suppose there is no way to pass socket attributes to another process and reconstruct it in the same without requesting for a separate connection.